# Make a toast if a slidingDrawer is opening?

Tags: android, listener, toast, slidingdrawer

Hi I would like to make a toast whenever a slidingDrawer is opening. I would like to know how i can listen if the slidingDrawer is opening and then make the toast if it is. I have looked everywhere but couldnt find a solution to the problem. Hope some of you can help :)

i found this on developer.android but could not figure out how to use it

```
    public void setOnDrawerCloseListener (SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener onDrawerCloseListener)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Activity` where you have your `SlidingDrawer`, you simply attach the listener like this:

**EDIT:**

Added more code:

The layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

The `Activity` `onCreate` method where you set the content view of the `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    SlidingDrawer mySlidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
    mySlidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SlidingDrawer opened!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Bear in mind, that the `SlidingDrawer` is actually deprecated in API 17 - it's discouraged to use it.

Comment: Hi would you be able to tell me how to define my slidingDrawer, I dont really know the command for a slidingDrawer and cant find the answer elsewhere? (connect the slidingDrawer in the xml with the java code) ^^ thx in advance

Comment: No problem ;-) - just remember that the `SlidingDrawer` has been deprecated, so in the future you might think of using something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
drawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
    }
});
```

Fill in `context`, `text` and `duration` according to your needs. I would like to inform you though, that `SlidingDrawer` is deprecated since API 17: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Comment: Damn it, my answer was quicker, it didn't contain any less information, nor it was any less precise, yet the questioner picked the other answer to comment on and ask more questions... :( I guess I am forever stuck at rep. 1. :D